# CSS for image gallery can't get uniform padding width around images

Tags: css, responsive-design

First off, I'm not good with CSS. And I'm having trouble with the divs that the images in my gallery are in. I'd like the divs to stay a uniform size as the page is resized but that's not happening. Basically, I'd like the images to have a 10 pixel "frame" on all sides of the image and maybe 5 pixels space between the images. Something like this:
[image]
And when the page is resized have it wrap something like this:
[image]

but what I'm actually getting is this:
[image]
and this when it wraps:
[image]
I know it's the CSS that's doing it, but I can't figure out how to write it so it does what I'd like. Here's the CSS I have:

```
    .single_image {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
}
.chap {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 0.75em; font-weight: 700; }

.container { 
  padding: 10px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap; 
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
}
.container div { 
  -webkit-box-flex: auto;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  flex: auto; 
  width: 120px; 
  margin: auto; 
}
```

and Here's the code for the whole page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Images</title>
<!-- fancybox CSS library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fbx/dist/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<!-- JS library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<!-- fancybox JS library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fbx/dist/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.single_image {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
}
.chap {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 0.75em; font-weight: 700; }

.container { 
  padding: 10px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap; 
  flex-flow: row wrap; 
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
}
.container div { 
  -webkit-box-flex: auto;
  -ms-flex: auto;
  flex: auto; 
  width: 120px; 
  margin: auto; 
}
</style>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
        <div class="single_image">
            <p class="page-header"></p>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="images/996118.jpg"><img src="images/996118.jpg" width="100px" /></a>
            <br><span class="chap">Image Text</span>
        </div>       
                    <div class="single_image">
            <p class="page-header"></p>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="images/111150.jpg"><img src="images/111150.jpg" width="100px" /></a>
            <br><span class="chap">Image Text</span>
        </div>       
                    <div class="single_image">
            <p class="page-header"></p>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="images/285201.jpg"><img src="images/285201.jpg" width="100px" /></a>
            <br><span class="chap">Image Text</span>
        </div>       
                    <div class="single_image">
            <p class="page-header"></p>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="images/273100.jpg"><img src="images/273100.jpg" width="100px" /></a>
            <br><span class="chap">Image Text</span>
        </div>       
                    <div class="single_image">
            <p class="page-header"></p>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="images/147287.jpg"><img src="images/147287.jpg" width="100px" /></a>
            <br><span class="chap">Image Text</span>
        </div>       
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block`.

```css
.single_image {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightblue;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 120px;
    display:inline-block
}
.chap {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 0.75em; font-weight: 700; }

.container { 
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="single_image">
            <p class="page-header"></p>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="images/996118.jpg"><img src="images/996118.jpg" width="100px" /></a>
            <br><span class="chap">Image Text</span>
        </div>       
                    <div class="single_image">
            <p class="page-header"></p>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="images/111150.jpg"><img src="images/111150.jpg" width="100px" /></a>
            <br><span class="chap">Image Text</span>
        </div>       
                    <div class="single_image">
            <p class="page-header"></p>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="images/285201.jpg"><img src="images/285201.jpg" width="100px" /></a>
            <br><span class="chap">Image Text</span>
        </div>       
                    <div class="single_image">
            <p class="page-header"></p>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="images/273100.jpg"><img src="images/273100.jpg" width="100px" /></a>
            <br><span class="chap">Image Text</span>
        </div>       
                    <div class="single_image">
            <p class="page-header"></p>
            <a class="fancybox" rel="gallery" href="images/147287.jpg"><img src="images/147287.jpg" width="100px" /></a>
            <br><span class="chap">Image Text</span>
        </div>
        </div>
```